# The character encodings on these files are different error in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

There is encoding error between last check in file and old one. How can i know the old check in encoding type.

I use UTF-8 (with signature) in Visiul studio 2008. I can save the encoding in IDE File-> Advanced Save Options. Some vs2008 don't display "Advanced Save Options" in File Tab.How can i display "Advanced Save Options" in File?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside VS, you can browse to the file in Source Control Explorer, right-click it and choose 'Properties'

From a Visual Studio Command Prompt, you can type: `tf properties $/path/to/file.cs` and the `File Type` line will tell you the current encoding. See the [Properties Command on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzy14b58.aspx) for more info.

When you add a new file, TFS will automatically determine the file encoding [based upon these rules](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/09/10/463281.aspx):

> First, a file with a Unicode byte
>   order mark (BOM) is added as that
>   particular type (UTF-8, UTF-16 big
>   endian, UTF-16 little endian, etc.).
>
> If a file doesn't have a BOM, we check
>   for an unprintable ASCII character in
>   the first 1 kilobyte of the file.  If
>   there is no unprintable ASCII
>   character in there, the encoding is
>   set to the current code page being
>   used, which is Windows-1252 on US
>   English Windows systems.
>
> If an unprintable character is
>   detected, the file is detected as
>   being binary.  The unprintable ASCII
>   characters detected are in the range
>   of 0 - 0x1F and 0x7F excluding 0x9
>   (TAB), 0xA (LF), 0xC (FF), 0xD (CR),
>   and 0x1A (^Z).

Comment: thanks for your helpful answer. I also find a way to see old checkin files encoding. 
In check in history, i open an older file in visual studio with right click->view.  File->Advanced Save Options will show us encoding type.

Comment: Grant what happens when you check the properties of both source and target and they both say utf-8? I'm getting the message from a merge conflict (tfs 2010) and both have utf-8.

Comment: Following up I find that while the properties of the file in source control showed utf-8 on one of them when I clicked detect it change to  the Windows-1252 one. I wonder why tfs was showing utf-8 until I said detect?

Comment: The referenced WWW page is now [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/buckh/how-tfs-version-control-determines-a-files-encoding/) and the rules used by Visual Studio changed 2 years after this answer was written.